# Union between two arrays in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've got the following tables:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| Second | 2 |

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Third | 3 |
| Fourth | 4 |

I want to build a formula that bring both together vertically, so that I end up with a big table like this:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| Second | 2 |
| Third | 3 |
| Fourth | 4 |

I've tried using standard union formulas like `{table1, table2}` but it adds table2 horizontally, not vertically.

Any thought on how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using curly braces, a comma (`{table1, table2}`) separates data into columns on the same row, while a semi-colon (`{table1; table2}`) will put `table2`'s data into the row after `table1`'s data.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that your local parameters will ask you tu write it as following

```
{table1; table2}
```